# Can't get my form to properly submit using CGI script. Also when submitted to my database my css isn't formatting my html doc

Tags: html, css

On my end, the html works fine, everything is formatted how it is suppose to be. However, when I go to submit to the database, it is not formatted correctly. Also, we are using a CGI script in order to basically send the email to whatever email is in the recipient, but on my database it does not work. Any ideas on what could be causing problems? Here is all of my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

legend {
  color: blue;
}

fieldset {
  color: brown;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<h1> Music Survey </h1>
<p> This form is being created to see what type of music you like, while also getting information on the overall importance of music in your life </p>

<form method="post" action="https://www.website.com">
  <input name="recipient" type="hidden" value="instructor@mail.com">
  <input name="required" type="hidden" value="email">
  <input name="return_link_url" type="hidden" value="http://student.mccinfo.net/~me/">
  <input name="return_link_title" type="hidden" value="Home">
  <input name="bgcolor" type="hidden" value="#EBAC9F">
  <input name="title" type="hidden" value="Thank you for taking the time to complete the form.">
  <input type="hidden" name="text_color" value="#000000">
  <input name="font_face" type="hidden" value="Arial,Helvetica">

  <label>First Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="first_name"><br><br>

  <label>Last Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="last_name"><br><br>

  <label>Email</label><br>
  <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>

  <fieldset>
    <legend> Select Your Favorite Types of Music</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pop"> Pop <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="classical"> Classical <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rock"> Rock <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="folk"> Folk <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Rap"> Rap <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="other"> Other <br>
  </fieldset><br>


  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select how often you purchase Music Cds:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="weekly"> Weekly <br>
    <input type="radio" name="few"> A few CDs each year <br>
    <input type="radio" name="monthly"> Monthly <br>
    <input type="radio" name="never"> Never Purchase <br>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
</form>

<div id="heads">Select the method you use most often to purchase Music:</div>
<select>
  <option label=" "> </option>
  <option value="online">Online</option>
  <option value="retail">Retail Store</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div id="head">What role does music play in your life?</div>
<textarea name="textbox" cols="60"> </textarea><br>
<br>

<input type="submit">Submit</input>
<input type="reset">Reset</input>
```

Comment: Saying that your received form data is "not formatted correctly" is not a helpful description of the problem. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? And what errors were encountered along the way?

Comment: @TheHeadRush well as you can see the snippet shows it gets formatted with the css style, but when i am putting it into my schools database, the style is no longer working (I haven't had this problem with other assignments)

Comment: We should talk about this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207213/room-for-the-head-rush-and-avery-o